# Trying to force a user after login to change password

Tags: asp.net-core-5.0

I'm trying to force an authenticated user to change password based on a database Boolean flag. I have used asp.net core resource filter to do that. When ChangePassword flag is on I'm hitting this error. If the ChangePassword flag is is false, application doesn't encounter any error.

*InvalidOperationException: If an IAsyncResourceFilter provides a result value by setting the Result property of ResourceExecutingContext to a non-null value, then it cannot call the next filter by invoking ResourceExecutionDelegate.*

My codes are as follows -

```
public class ChangePasswordFilter: IAsyncResourceFilter
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IUrlHelperFactory _urlHelperFactory;

    public ChangePasswordFilter(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _urlHelperFactory = urlHelperFactory;
    }

    public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var HttpContext = context.HttpContext;
        var urlHelper = _urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(context);
        
        var redirectUrl = urlHelper.Page("/UserManagement/ChangePassword");
        var currentUrl = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;

        if (redirectUrl != currentUrl)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.HttpContext.User);
            if (user?.ChangePassword ?? false)
            {
                //context.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectUrl);
                context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("ChangePassword", "UserManagement", new { ReturnUrl = HttpContext.Request.Path });
            }
        }

        await next();
    }
```

And in startup.ConfigureServices

```
services.AddScoped<ChangePasswordFilter>();

services.AddMvc(o =>
            {
                o.Filters.Add(typeof(ChangePasswordFilter));
            });
```

This example is taken from this answer

[Force user change password when loading any webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57557761/force-user-change-password-when-loading-any-webpage/67893098)

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, while trying to implement this same code.
I did add `return;` after `context.Result`, and my code is working fine.
My code:

```
context.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectUrl);
return;
```

Hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The link you referenced is for a question on asp.net core 2.0. There are many differences between asp.net core 2.0 and asp.net core 5.0.

However, the error message is quite clear. You are invoking the ResourceExecutionDelegate after setting the ResourceExecutingContext Result property to a non-null value.

I'm not too familiar with ResourceFilters but what happens if you replace `await next();` with `return;`?

Comment: If you replace `await next();` with `return;`, it makes a infinite loop.