# Force user to change password in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: passwords, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-5.0

I am working on a web application using ASP.NET Core 5 Razor Pages.

I have created a custom user class named `ApplicationUser` and added `LastPasswordChange (Nullable DateTime)` to it. In this application, I want to force users to change their password under two conditions:

1. If LastPasswordChange is null, means the user is created by the admin and the next login will be the user's first login.
2. If LastPasswordChange is more than the password expired period. (certain number of days)

How can I force users to change their password given these conditions? And there always is a chance to input URL to access other pages. How to block those URL as well?

Answer (score 0):

I tried as below:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [PersonalData]
        public string? LastPassword { get; set; }
        [PersonalData]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    }
```

in Login Page Model:

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;
        

        public LoginModel(SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager, 
            
            UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            
        }
      ........
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
          ......
           var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
            var lastpswd = user!=null?user.LastPassword:null;
            if (lastpswd == null)
            {
                return LocalRedirect("The url to resetthepassword");
            }
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
          ......
         }
     }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I need to force them to change password, not reset. I've found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57557761/force-user-change-password-when-loading-any-webpage, and it's working as requirements